# render dynamically different children inside the same parent?

Tags: reactjs

I wonder if that's possible to render dynamically different children inside the same parent?

I explain my self for example you got the react component P as a parent and you would like to display C1 (child 1) inside your child list and not the CX.

it's that possible ?

I found some tip about how to do it but it's not very dynamic... I still show you

```
 export const handleTemplate = (
   component_type : string
 ): JSX.Element | null => {
   let template = null;
   if (component_type === "type1") template = ComponentType1;
   else if (component_type === "type2") template = ComponentType2;
    ...
   return template;
 };
```

Comment: This seems correct. Did you try ?

Comment: Yup I tried it, it's working fine but I wonder it's possible to do better ?  Indeed I don't know if this kind of problem is solvable but I would like to add other "type" without adding 'if' condition at each

Comment: You can create a function with a switch or use react router to split your components. But this is fine like this.

Comment: With a switch ?  can you give me a little example or send me doc about what you mean ? Yes I through about route but I must keep the same URL route that's the problem :/  Oh so if it's currently the best way to do it I will keep it thx you helped me :)

Answer (score 0):

the best practice is to have a constant hash map of all type to component mapping like this:

```
const TYPE_TO_COMPONENT = {
  type1: ComponentType1,
  type2: ComponentType2,
}

export const handleTemplate = (
   component_type : string
 ): JSX.Element | null => {
   return TYPE_TO_COMPONENT[component_type];
 };
```